# How to remove a space in a heading name in a output file

Tags: vba

I have the following code that reads csv files and creates text (ied) files for some simulations i run. In the output text (ied files). The time and flow data is written. The heading of each station is also written. The station headings are obtained from the csv files. So for example, ReFH2 output for Kelwell Drain,25-hr storm.csv is read and the file ReFH Total flow Kelwell Drain,25-hr storm.csv is produced. then a ied text file is written with the time and flow data

```
    QTBDY
Kelwell Drain
       106     0.000     0.000     HOURS    EXTEND    LINEAR               0.000
     0.369     0.000
     0.362     1.000
     0.359     2.000
     0.359     3.000
     0.364     4.000
     0.374     5.000
     0.392     6.000
     0.418     7.000
     0.453     8.000
     0.496     9.000
     0.552    10.000
     0.622    11.000
     0.710    12.000
     0.819    13.000
     0.945    14.000
     1.083    15.000
     1.222    16.000
     1.352    17.000
     1.463    18.000
     1.544    19.000
     1.589    20.000
     1.599    21.000
     1.582    22.000
     1.542    23.000
     1.486    24.000
     1.420    25.000
     1.349    26.000
     1.273    27.000
     1.194    28.000
     1.114    29.000
     1.034    30.000
     0.953    31.000
     0.874    32.000
     0.801    33.000
     0.733    34.000
     0.672    35.000
     0.619    36.000
     0.574    37.000
     0.538    38.000
     0.507    39.000
     0.481    40.000
     0.459    41.000
     0.440    42.000
     0.424    43.000
     0.410    44.000
     0.398    45.000
     0.387    46.000
     0.377    47.000
     0.369    48.000
     0.000    49.000
     0.000    50.000
     0.000    51.000
     0.000    52.000
     0.000    53.000
     0.000    54.000
     0.000    55.000
     0.000    56.000
     0.000    57.000
     0.000    58.000
     0.000    59.000
     0.000    60.000
     0.000    61.000
     0.000    62.000
     0.000    63.000
     0.000    64.000
     0.000    65.000
     0.000    66.000
     0.000    67.000
     0.000    68.000
     0.000    69.000
     0.000    70.000
     0.000    71.000
     0.000    72.000
     0.000    73.000
     0.000    74.000
     0.000    75.000
     0.000    76.000
     0.000    77.000
     0.000    78.000
     0.000    79.000
     0.000    80.000
     0.000    81.000
     0.000    82.000
     0.000    83.000
     0.000    84.000
     0.000    85.000
     0.000    86.000
     0.000    87.000
     0.000    88.000
     0.000    89.000
     0.000    90.000
     0.000    91.000
     0.000    92.000
     0.000    93.000
     0.000    94.000
     0.000    95.000
     0.000    96.000
     0.000    97.000
     0.000    98.000
     0.000    99.000
     0.000   100.000
     0.000   101.000
     0.000   102.000
     0.000   103.000
     0.000   104.000
     0.000   105.000
```

here as can be seen the word Kelwell Drain has a space between them. i don't want this space. i want it to say KelwellDrain. I am not sure how to do this i have tried the following code

```
station_name = Replace(station_name, " ", "")
```

but it is not working.

the full code is here

```
    Option Explicit
Dim ReFH_files() As Variant
Dim num_ReFH_files As Integer
Dim Stations() As Variant
Dim num_stations As Integer
Dim Storm_Lengths() As Variant
Dim num_storm_lengths As Integer
Dim Total_Flow_files() As Variant
Dim WorkingFolder As String
Dim Return_Periods() As Integer
Dim num_return_periods As Integer

Dim root_name_ReFH As String
Dim root_name_TotalFlow As String
Dim root_name_StormLength As String
Dim header_text_to_match As String
Dim start_row As Integer
Dim start_col As Integer

Sub ProcessReFH_Files()
' Get the data and write it on the sheet for info
GetSummaryReFHData

' Create the Total Flow files from the refh files
ExtractTotalFlows

' Now create the ied files
CreateIEDFiles

End Sub

Sub SetWorkingFolder()

WorkingFolder = GetFolder
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 11).Value = WorkingFolder

End Sub

Sub CreateIEDFiles()
Dim output_filename As String
Dim input_filename As String
Dim total_flow_filename As String
Dim fileOut As Integer
Dim fileIn As Integer

Dim station_name As String
Dim storm_length As String
Dim return_period As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim dataLine As String, outputLine As String
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim time As Double, strTime As String
Dim flow As Double, strFlow As String
Dim num_data As Integer

' For each storm length create one ied file per return period
For i = 0 To num_storm_lengths - 1
    storm_length = Storm_Lengths(i)
    Debug.Print storm_length
    For j = 0 To num_return_periods - 1
        return_period = Return_Periods(j + 1)
        Debug.Print return_period
        ' output file name
        output_filename = root_name_StormLength & storm_length & "_Return_Period_" & return_period & ".ied"
        Debug.Print output_filename
        fileOut = FreeFile()
        ' Open the output file
        output_filename = WorkingFolder & "\" & output_filename
        Open output_filename For Output As #fileOut

        ' loop through the station files
        For k = 0 To num_stations - 1
            station_name = Stations(k)
            ' write the station standard station data
            Print #fileOut, "QTBDY"
            station_name = Replace(station_name, " ", "")
            Print #fileOut, Trim(station_name)



            total_flow_filename = GetTotalFlowFileName(station_name, storm_length)
            Debug.Print total_flow_filename
            input_filename = total_flow_filename
            fileIn = FreeFile()
            ' Open the station file for this storm length and read the flow for this return period
            input_filename = WorkingFolder & "\" & input_filename
            Open input_filename For Input As #fileIn
            ' count the number of lines (this is very inefficient!
            num_data = 0
            While Not EOF(fileIn)
                Line Input #fileIn, dataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
                If (Len(dataLine) > 1) Then
                    num_data = num_data + 1
                End If
            Wend
            num_data = num_data - 1
            Close #fileIn

            ' write the data header
            'num_data = 120
            outputLine = Right(Space(10) & num_data, 10)
            outputLine = outputLine & "     0.000     0.000     HOURS    EXTEND    LINEAR               0.000"
            Print #fileOut, outputLine

            ' open the file again
            Open input_filename For Input As #fileIn
            ' Read the first line
            Line Input #fileIn, dataLine
            ' read the rest of the lines, extracting the time and the flow for this return period
            While Not EOF(fileIn)
                Line Input #fileIn, dataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
                dataArray = Split(dataLine, ",")
                flow = CDbl(dataArray(j + 1))
                strTime = dataArray(0)
                time = GetDecimalTime(strTime)
                ' make the numbers 3dp and string 10 characters wide
                strFlow = Right(Space(10) & Format(flow, "0.000"), 10)
                strTime = Right(Space(10) & Format(time, "0.000"), 10)
                outputLine = strFlow & strTime
                Print #fileOut, outputLine
            Wend
            Close #fileIn
        Next k

        ' close the ied file
        Close #fileOut
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
Sub ExtractTotalFlows()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim filename As String, output_filename As String
Dim fileNum As Integer, output_fileNum As Integer
Dim dataLine As String
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim dataCols() As Integer
Dim num_cols As Integer
Dim outputLine As String

Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer
Dim return_period As String

For i = 0 To num_ReFH_files - 1
    filename = WorkingFolder & "\" & ReFH_files(i)
    output_filename = WorkingFolder & "\" & Total_Flow_files(i)

    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Input As #fileNum

    output_fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open output_filename For Output As #output_fileNum

    ' read the first line
    Line Input #fileNum, dataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
    dataArray = Split(dataLine, ",")
    ' Get the columns where we want data
    num_cols = 1
    ReDim dataCols(0 To UBound(dataArray))
    ReDim Return_Periods(0 To UBound(dataArray))

    dataCols(0) = 0 ' time
    For j = 0 To UBound(dataArray)
        If (InStr(1, dataArray(j), header_text_to_match) > 0) Then
            dataCols(num_cols) = j

            ' Take this opportunity to get the return period of this flow
            ' Find the first (
            i1 = InStr(1, dataArray(j), "(")
            ' Find the next " "
            i2 = InStr(i1 + 1, dataArray(j), " ")
            ' get the return period integer
            return_period = Mid(dataArray(j), i1 + 1, i2 - i1)
            Return_Periods(num_cols) = CInt(return_period)

            ' write it to the summary sheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(start_row + num_cols, start_col + 4).Value = return_period

            num_cols = num_cols + 1
        End If
    Next j

    ReDim Preserve dataCols(0 To num_cols - 1)
    ReDim Preserve Return_Periods(0 To num_cols - 1)
    num_return_periods = num_cols - 1
    ' Write out this data
    outputLine = ""
    For j = 0 To num_cols - 1
        outputLine = outputLine & """" & dataArray(dataCols(j)) & """"
        If (j <> num_cols - 1) Then
            outputLine = outputLine & ","
        End If
    Next j
    'Debug.Print outputLine
    Print #output_fileNum, outputLine

    ' Now read and write the data
    While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, dataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        dataArray = Split(dataLine, ",")
        outputLine = ""
        For j = 0 To num_cols - 1
            outputLine = outputLine & dataArray(dataCols(j))
            If (j <> num_cols - 1) Then
                outputLine = outputLine & ","
            End If
        Next j
        Print #output_fileNum, outputLine
    Wend

    Close #fileNum
    Close #output_fileNum
Next i

End Sub

Function GetSummaryReFHData()
Dim i As Integer
Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer
Dim file_name As String
Dim station_name As String
Dim storm_length As String
Dim total_flow_file_name As String

'get the root names
root_name_ReFH = ActiveSheet.Cells(17, 4).Value
root_name_TotalFlow = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 4).Value
root_name_StormLength = ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 4).Value
header_text_to_match = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 4).Value

WorkingFolder = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 11).Value

' read all the names of the files
ReFH_files = listfiles(WorkingFolder, root_name_ReFH)
num_ReFH_files = UBound(ReFH_files) + 1

' extract all of the station names
ReDim Total_Flow_files(0 To num_ReFH_files - 1)
ReDim Stations(0 To num_ReFH_files - 1)
ReDim Storm_Lengths(0 To num_ReFH_files - 1)
For i = 0 To num_ReFH_files - 1
    file_name = ReFH_files(i)

    ' extract the station
    ' It is the characters from the end of the root name to the comma
    i1 = Len(root_name_ReFH) + 1
    i2 = InStr(1, file_name, ",")
    station_name = Mid(file_name, i1, i2 - i1)
    Stations(i) = station_name

    ' Make the total flow filename from this data
    total_flow_file_name = root_name_TotalFlow & Mid(file_name, i1)
    Total_Flow_files(i) = total_flow_file_name

    ' extract the storm length
    ' It is the characters from the comma to the -hr
    i1 = InStr(1, file_name, ",") + 1
    i2 = InStr(1, file_name, "-hr")
    storm_length = Mid(file_name, i1, i2 - i1)
    Storm_Lengths(i) = CInt(storm_length)



Next i
' Get the unique entries from these lists
Stations = ArrayUnique(Stations)
num_stations = UBound(Stations) + 1

Storm_Lengths = ArrayUnique(Storm_Lengths)
num_storm_lengths = UBound(Storm_Lengths) + 1

' Write the info found

Dim myrow As Integer, mycol As Integer

start_row = 7
start_col = 11 ' col K

' Clear any existing  data
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(start_row, start_col), Cells(start_row + 1000, start_col + 50)).Clear

myrow = start_row
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = "Station names"
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Font.Bold = True

ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 4).Value = "Return Periods"
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 4).Font.Bold = True


For i = 0 To num_stations - 1
    myrow = myrow + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = Stations(i)
Next i

myrow = myrow + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = "Storm lengths"
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Font.Bold = True
For i = 0 To num_storm_lengths - 1
    myrow = myrow + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = Storm_Lengths(i)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 1).Value = "hours"
Next i

myrow = myrow + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = "ReFH files"
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 5).Value = "Total Flowfiles"
ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 5).Font.Bold = True
For i = 0 To num_ReFH_files - 1
    myrow = myrow + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col).Value = ReFH_files(i)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(myrow, start_col + 5).Value = Total_Flow_files(i)
Next i
End Function



Function GetTotalFlowFileName(station_name As String, storm_length As String) As String
' returns the Total_Flow filename searching the Total_Flow_files array to match the station name and storm length
On Error GoTo err:

Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim station_storm_length_str As String

GetTotalFlowFileName = ""
For i = 0 To num_ReFH_files - 1
    station_storm_length_str = station_name & ", " & storm_length
    i2 = InStr(1, Total_Flow_files(i), station_storm_length_str)
    If (i2 > 0) Then
        GetTotalFlowFileName = Total_Flow_files(i)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

err:
    i = 0
End Function
```

Comment: Are you certain that it's a space and not another whitespace characted between the words in `Kelwell Drain`? Your code `station_name = Replace(station_name, " ", "")` looks correct to me.

Comment: Okay is it in the correct place. I am just getting it from the file name, i just thought it would be a space. if it is a white space character how do i remove that. i have the trim function following it, so i am confused

Comment: Highlight the "space" in one of the lines and copy it, then switch to the VB editor and in the immediate window type ? ASC("   then do control V to paste your space and then immediately ") and then press enter. It should respond with a number - if it's a real space it will be 32

Comment: I have done what you say and it returns nothing. what does that mean

Comment: Try putting a space in there so ? ASC(" ")
Does that return 32 when you press enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have managed to resolve the issue

```
 ' loop through the station files
    For k = 0 To num_stations - 1
        station_name = Stations(k)
        ' write the station standard station data
        Print #fileOut, "QTBDY"
        Corr_station_name = Replace(station_name, " ", "")
        Print #fileOut, Trim(Corr_station_name)
```

I just created another Dim called corr_station_name.